# Micro SD Card reader on Lenovo N22 not working Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, 17.04, lenovo, sd-card

I have a Lenovo N22 laptop and the micro sd card reader is not working.

I configured a dual boot system with Xubuntu 17.04. With different tools, like gparted or the file manager,  I cannot see the Microsd card reader, with or without a micro sd card in place (I can read the micro sd card with an external usb card reader).

I executed lscpi -v and it shows this information for the SD controller:

00:12.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SD Controller (rev 21) (prog-if 01)

```
Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SD Controller

Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
Memory at 91315000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the /dev folder to see if the SD card is showing up there. They should show up as "mmcblkX" in this folder, with X being the number of the card (probably 0). In the terminal, you can use the command `ls /dev | grep "mmc"`. If that command spits out stuff, then the system sees the SD card, but your graphical tools like gparted don't (which is a different problem).

There may have also been some problem with the device, in which case the driver might have spit out some useful error when you plugged it in. Plug the SD card in the slot, and then run `sudo dmesg | tail` (soon after plugging it in) to see these messages. That might help you get started.

Comment: The unit mmcblk0 is the hard drive of the laptop. It has several partitions:

Comment: Some of the less expensive laptops these days use eMMC, where the main drive is basically an SD card soldered to the motherboard. Did you see any errors print out in the log, user3394635?